# Batch Script: Listing Files that are Missing

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script that will go through a load of files and append the names of the files that are missing into a text file called ''doesnotexist''. The files have a format:

13050122, 13050216 (yy, mm, dd, hh), and it's the missing days that I'm interested in picking out.

So here's the script I've got so far:

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set year=13
set "ext=.edt
pause
for /l %%a in (*501*,1,*531*) do ( 
    pause
    IF EXIST "%%a" (
        ECHO "%%a" exists
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%b doesn't exist >> file_pathway\doesnotexist.txt
    )
)
```

The script runs, but it fills the doesnotexist.txt file with:

```
0 doesn't exist  
%b doesn't exist
```

Does anyone know how I would go about listing the days that are missing. I hope that makes sense.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Without attempting to incorporate a method to determine how many days there are in any particular month, including those in possible leap years your question is simply a request for a script.

Comment: For pure batch I suggest using [date and time functions](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/#date-and-time-functions) especially `DateToMJD` and `MJDToDate` iterating from a start to an end date and an additional `for /l` loop for the hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple way to solve this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A "year=13, feb=28+^!(year%%4)"
set i=0
for %%a in (31 %feb% 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "dpm[!i!]=%%a"
)
set i=100
for /L %%m in (1,1,12) do (
   set /A i+=1
   for /L %%d in (1,1,!dpm[%%m]!) do (
      IF EXIST "%year%!i:~1!%%d*" (
         ECHO "%year%!i:~1!%%d" exists
      ) ELSE (
         ECHO %year%!i:~1!%%d doesn't exist >> file_pathway\doesnotexist.txt
      )
   )
)
```

But, beware! This method will fail on february of year 2400! **`;)`**

Comment: 2400 (also 2000) is OK, it's the other hundred multiples who will fail. Use `set /A "year=%%f, feb=28+(^!(year%%4)^&(^!(^!(year%%100)))^|(^!(year%%400)))"` for correct leap year handling (I enjoy wasting time on small shits :) ).